Authorizing Access to apache http application using mod_rewrite rules
i am a bit new to apache web server and mod_rewrite .
We are hosting a cgi application on apache web server  We are trying to add an authorization check to verify whether the user has access to the application resource ( there is an in house api ,lets say Authorize API that we call using the users kereberos and which lets us know if the user has access to the application or not).
Lets say the application is hosted at endpoint /cgi-bin/DocViewer.cgi
What i am trying  to do is to use Apache's mod_rewrite to first rewrite the application url to a custom end point (lets say /authorize/access_control.py ) where i want the authorization check to happen and set APACHE Env variable lets say AUTH_STATUS to 200 if user is authorized or set it to 403 if failed.
So depending on the ENV variable AUTH_STATUS , i again rewrite to the application endpoint /cgi-bin/DocViewer.cgi
The apache httpd.conf rewrite logic i am using here is :
    ReWriteEngine On
    ReWriteRule ^ - [E=ACCESS_CONTROL_CHK:0]
    ReWriteRule ^ - [E=ORIGINAL_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]

    ReWriteCond "%{ENV:ACCESS_CONTROL_CHK}" "!=1"
    ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/
    ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/authorize/access_control.py$

    ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /authorize/access_control.py [E=ACCESS_CONTROL_CHK:1]


    #add RewriteCond for AUTH_STATUS=200. {to do}
    ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:ORIGINAL_URI} [L]



So my query is when i rewrite Request URI to /authorize/access_control.py ,will the server process the request to /authorize/access_control.py so that this endpoint can set apache environment var  AUTH_STATUS to 200/403 or it will just get rewritten back to original request uri without any processing?
So being new to apache http server am i following the right approach here using rewrite , if not can you please suggest a more doable approach. Thanks
